# Run the recorded testplan in Jmeter and verify the the entry in the Database

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Im using Jmeter and do performance testing for my web application. I record my actions in jmeter and play back the same. The testplan got run but when i verify the database manually, the new row is not created. The value got added in the existing line.Please help me out of this. I am struck in this step for 2 days

Comment: Could you please add more info? What you mean with "the new row is not created. The value got added in the existing line": Is your app "updating" a register in the DB instead of creating a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify if your requests includes hardcoded session's data. If your app manages sessions and you just "recorded" the actions, probably you are re-using the same session's data. Assuming there is a login page -> the requests after the login would use a session, usually returned for the login action.

Comment: Thanks for your Comment Diego. We are using the same session while replay it. How to control it Diego? I am new to JMeter.

Comment: Try just deleting the session info from the requests: it is, if your request looks like http://server/method?i=UdLXRgolABcAADjbG4AAAAAS then try removing everything after the method's name. Newest jmeter versions manages cookies automagically. Include an "HTTP Cookie Manager" in your plan

Comment: I have clear the sessions in each request and run my recorded testplan. Same thing happen. Im using Apache jmeter 2.13 version. Normally how it works while record and play. Can you explain please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As comments are not enough descriptive; posting a new answer. You can do this by using regular expression extractors, because -probably- the session info comes in the response (so extract it into a variable, by parsing the response with a regex extractor)

[image]

and then use the variable in further request/s.

[image]

This is a tricky way and need lot of work... even more if the session keep changing in subsequent responses (it usually change while moving worward through the page/app workflow), if that is the case you will need to extract the data after each request. 
Please reffer to the [jmeter manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) for more info about regex extractors.